# Creating workflow and node in Java

Tags: java, workflow, scheduling, nodes

I would like to create the workflow which is based on the node
for example
[image]

each node will contains information such as

1. `int` time
2. `int` cost
3. `arraylist` relationship
4. `boolean` is_traveled.

However, I am not really sure how to build workflow with nodes.

I keep searching "workflow"(Directed acyclic graph) and "node" but I can't find reasonable resources.

Can anybody give some example or useful resource ?

Comment: What exactly is "*workflow*" in this context?

Comment: workflow is Directed acyclic graph which contain nodes

Comment: OK. Let me ask differently.  What do you expect your program to do?  Do you have a definite algorithm?

Comment: I am not building algorithm. I am studying interview.And , I was studying BFS and Searching nodes from DAG.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this paper](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/s99cs170/notes/lec13.pdf)?

Comment: Yep :). However, I am preparing coding questions. Therefore, I was searching how to code such DAG with BFS searching.(Like using class object to implement DAG and some simple searching algorithms.)